# What effect does Swift's lack of dynamic capabilities have when developing?

Tags: swift

I am CS student relatively new to Cocoa/CocoaTouch and I am trying to understand the nature of OS X/iOS dev. I understand the difference between dynamic and static languages.

> Static languages have all variables bound to a type etc. Variables are bound during execution for dynamic etc.

However, when I am developing OS X apps I struggle to see the examples where dynamic functionality would change things? Can someone explain what someone explain what Obj-C can support that Swift fundamentally cannot when developing apps?
I have come across many cases where the lack of flexibility has forced me to refactor my code, but that's not what I am talking about, or am I confused?

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/122205/what-is-the-supposed-productivity-gain-of-dynamic-typing has some good responses on this from a programmer perspective

Comment: The most glaring difference between ObjC and Swift: reflection. The ObjC Run Time functions provide much richer introspection capabilities than Swift's `Mirror`

Comment: Just an example. You can change the class of an Obj-C object to a subclass just by setting a value. You can replace existing method by a different method at runtime (method swizzling). You can have an object with no methods that will dynamically generate functionality depending on method name you try to call on it. You can use class different from what a method expects provided they both have the same set of methods... and the list goes on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can someone explain what someone explain what Obj-C can support that Swift fundamentally cannot when developing apps

What I used to take advantage of in Objective-C was not so much dynamic *typing* as dynamic *messaging*. The whole messaging apparatus can be rejiggered at runtime, from simple key-value coding or `performSelector` to dynamic injection of methods into a class at runtime, method swizzling, and key-value observing.

You can *do* all those things in Swift, but only provided you are talking to Objective-C (i.e. this is an NSObject). That's because all of those things are actually *done* in Objective-C. You could not, for example, implement even the most basic key-value coding in pure Swift, in the absence of Foundation, as Swift has neither dynamic messaging nor true introspection.

From the point of view of practical app programming, however, I don't miss any of that. For one thing, I *am* always talking to Objective-C, because Cocoa *is* in Objective-C. For another thing, it turns out that most of these tricks weren't really necessary, and I've mostly found other ways to accomplish my practical goals. I do still use some key-value coding (especially to do tricks like store an arbitrary value inside a CALayer), but on the whole I've cut way back on my use of such stuff, mostly thanks to the fact that functions are first-class citizens in Swift.

As for dynamic *typing*, I don't miss it for an instant; changing to Swift has actually *saved* me from mistakes that I was making without even realizing it because of dynamic typing imposed on me by the APIs (e.g. the fact that `objectAtIndex:` returned an `id` — though, to be sure, this is less likely to trouble you today thanks to "lightweight generics").

Comment: thanks for the answer. What do you mean by " mostly thanks to the fact that functions are first-class citizens in Swift"

Comment: I mean you don't need to form method calls dynamically because method calls are like objects - you can make arrays of them, pass them around, etc.